# Date Input field default value in Outsystems

Tags: outsystems

I run into this problem where I would want the date field to display "YYYY-MM-DD" instead of the default 1900-01-01.

I tried to to assign the date field variable, which is named ContractStart, with this value:

```
If (ContractStart = NullDate(), "YYYY-MM-DD", ContractStart)
```

And, it won't allow me:

Date data type required instead of text.

Is there a workaround for this inorder for me to show "YYYY-MM-DD" if the user hasn't chosen a date?

I've also posted this question in the OutSystems Forum:
https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/17164/textbox-default-date-value/

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution:

You need to click on the Date Input Box itself...in this case the -ContractStart

And then set the ff values:

NullValue: NullDate()
Prompt: "YYYY-MM-DD"